# Google Sheet Appscript only collects my username and no other users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a changelog script that only collects my username and does not collect for any other user. I'm trying to figure out the bug but unable to find a solution.

[image]

```
function changelog_script(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetNameTracker = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
    if (sheetNameTracker !== "Changelog") {
        let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Changelog');
        var range = e.range && e.range.getA1Notation(); 
        var user = e.user.getUsername();
        var function_source = "changelog_script";
        var time = new Date();
        var changeType = e.changeType || 'EDIT'; 
        console.log(user);
        var oldValue = e.oldValue;
        var newValue = e.value;
        var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
        sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, 8).setValues([
        [time.toLocaleString(), function_source, changeType, sheetNameTracker, range, user, oldValue, newValue]]);
    }
}



function onChange(e) {
    if (e.changeType == "EDIT") return;
    changelog_script(e);
}
```

[Example Google Sheet with attached App script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G6hReDABOeMuLvS7kAL-THNZ_vxMB2frILFCelxdv1A/edit#gid=1913152817).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and ran some tests, I tested it with different users under the same Google Sheet. With 2 users inside the same Workspace account, it works. However, accessing using a Gmail.com account on the same sheet doesn't work. I think the issue might be the security restrictions of the users. The Google Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#:%7E:text=amin%40example.com-,Change,-(installable)) states that the value of the user `depends on a complex set of security restrictions`.

Also, in the Google Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser), it states that

> If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity,
> `User.getEmail()` returns a blank string.
>
> The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for
> example, the user's email address is not available in any context that
> allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a
> simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google
> Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized
> by the developer instead of the user). However, these restrictions
> generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or
> belongs to the same Google Workspace domain as the user.

*Note: I think this is setup this way do to security, because some users can use this feature in a malicious way to capture the email address of users without they noticing*